# Adding custom zones for web parts to all subsites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, web-part

I need to add several custom `WebPartZone` to all pages on my SP 2010 portal. I supposed that if I changed masterpage by adding WebPartZones to it, it'll be on all pages after I check **Reset all subsites to inherit this system masterpage setting** on `<portal_url>/_Layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx`. But zones aren't appear and there is error:

```
Cannot complete this action.
Please try again.<nativehr>0x80004005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

Comment: Can you check the ULS logs for a more specific error message? And exactly when is this error thrown?

Comment: This error is thrown when I click "Edit Page" on "Site Actions" menu.

Comment: As far as I remember, you can't define WebPartZones in Masterpage you must define them in the PageTemplates and place a Placeholder for the Webpart-Zone in the masterpage. That's how I solved it in a project. @Robert Lindgren was faster.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you can not add WebPartZones to your masterpage. You will had to add it to pages and page layouts. http://www.novolocus.com/2008/10/13/so-can-you-put-web-part-zones-in-master-pages-or-what/

Comment: but when I add custom WebPartZone to materpage, it's displayed on the mainpage of my portal. What's wrong with the subsites?

Comment: Don't know. A better approach would be to add a User Control in your master page

Comment: Are you sure, that all subsites use the new masterpage?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, because on the
    _Layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx
I checked Reset all subsites to inherit this system master page setting

Comment: Which will only work on publishing sites